# the difference of calculating final state in G4ParticleHPFissionFS

Tags: geant4

In 'G4ParticleHPFissionFS', I find that it used   'G4ParticleHPFSFissionFS', 'G4ParticleHPFCFissionFS',   'G4ParticleHPSCFissionFS', 'G4ParticleHPTCFissionFS', 'G4ParticleHPLCFissionFS', 'G4ParticleHPFFFissionFS'. I think all these class are used to calculate the final state. But what is the difference between  them?

thanks!I am waiting for your help!